# Hound of Tindalos tiebreaker?

Tags: arkham-horror

The Hound of Tindalos says that it automatically moves to the closest investigator.  Which investigator does it target in the case of two equidistant investigators in different locations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/AHfaq.pdf):

> **Q:** Who determines where a Hound of Tindalos moves if two investigators are tied in being nearest to the hound?
>
> **A:** As per the rules governing flying monsters, the hound will go after the investigator with the lower Sneak value. In case of a tie, the first player chooses.